# How to output a string when the mouse is within a certain x/y coordinate

Tags: user-interface, pygame

I am writing a hangman game for fun and cannot for the life of me figure out what has gone wrong with my code. When I select the A on the GUI, no matter the y coordinate it will select A, or B or vice versa.

I have tried to change the operators around in case it was a logic error but nothing happened.

```
def mainGame(length, Base, Wall, Roof, Rope):
    global characterSelected
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] >= 50 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] >= 100:
                    if pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] >= 82 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] >= 132:
                        win.blit(Blank, (50, 100))
                        characterSelected = 'A'
                        characterValidation(length, word, 'A', Base, Wall, Roof, Rope)
```

I expect it to only select A when the cursor is inside the box, but it does it anywhere within the same x coordinates, but not the Y coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't use Stack Overflow for debugging help. Some actually debugging or just some thoughtful analysis would show you the problem.

Your first condition is checking whether the cursor is to the right or below (50,100), and the second condition is checking whether the cursor is to the right or below (82, 132). You probably want to check whether `pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]` is between 50 and 82 and whether `pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]` is between 100 and 132.